# Error al leer datos de Sql Server en c# con dataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

tengo un problema al leer datos de sql server.

tengo un procedimiento que me devuelve estos datos y otros mas que no pongo porque la imagen se me hace muy larga.
[image: imagen de base de datos]

Este es mi código donde leo los datos en c#

```
            var dbSql = new DatabaseSql();
            dbSql.ProcedureName = "tesp_List_Reportes_Tarea";
            dbSql.AddParameter("ide", System.Data.DbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, cliente_id);
            List<ReporteTareas> reportes = new List<ReporteTareas>();
            //ReporteTareas reporte;
            using (var registros = dbSql.GetDataReader())
            {
                while (registros.Read())
                {
                   //reporte = new ReporteTareas();
                   var id = registros["id"];
                   var tipo_documento = registros["tipo_id"];
                   var titulo = registros["titulo"];
                   var detalle = registros["detalle"];
                   var codigo = registros["codigo"];
                   var version = registros["version"];
                   var turno = registros["turno"];
                   var nombre = registros["nombre"];
                   var lugar = registros["lugar"];
                   var fecha = registros["fecha"];
                   ReporteTareas reporte = new ReporteTareas();
                   reporte.id = int.Parse(id.ToString());
                   reporte.tipo_documento = int.Parse(tipo_documento.ToString());
                   reporte.titulo = (titulo.ToString());
                   reporte.detalle = (detalle.ToString());
                   reporte.codigo = (codigo.ToString());
                   // reporte.version = int.Parse(version.ToString());
                   reporte.turno = int.Parse(turno.ToString());
                   reporte.nombre = (nombre.ToString());
                   reporte.lugar = (lugar.ToString());
                   reporte.fecha = (fecha.ToString());
                   lista.add(reporte);
                }
            }
```

Lo extraño es que lee correctamente todos los datos hasta que llega a versión, Ese decir si se conecta con la base de datos y me lee los demás datos excepto este y cuando lo comento si me ejecuta bien pero sin el dato, y la razón por la que no cambio el dato es porque me sale el mismo error en otras consultas.

este es el error que me sale cuando depuro mi código

[image: error]

Comment: que libreria usas para acceder a los datos, porqe veo el metodo `GetDataReader()` pero esto no es ado.net, o si?

Answer (score -2):

El error se encontraba en el orden en que llamaba los datos, como se ve en la imagen primero me trae versión y después código.

cambie esto

```
                   var detalle = registros["detalle"];
                   var codigo = registros["codigo"];
                   var version = registros["version"];
                   var turno = registros["turno"];
```

por esto

```
                   var detalle = registros["detalle"];
                   var version = registros["version"];
                   var codigo = registros["codigo"];
                   var turno = registros["turno"];
```

con esto se arreglo mi error

Comment: Esa no puede ser la solucion, el orden no genera un exception, si lo hace es porque la libreria que usas tiene un defecto, si harias eso mismo usando ado.net no tendrias ese problema